# Nginx reverse proxy for ElasticSearch allowing _search endpoint only

Tags: angularjs, security, nginx, proxy, elasticsearch

I know how to allow only GET request (more here http://brudtkuhl.com/securing-elasticsearch/), but in my case it would be better to configure nginx reverse proxy to allow only _search endpoint. And I can't find a way how I can do it.
Can anyone help me?

Just to be clear I'm going to query elasticsearch using angularjs. I would like to make it as fast as possible. I can't leave it absolutely open but narrowing query to _search enpoint would be perfect. Seems like Nginx is capable of doing that but I don't know how.

Must be some "if" statement inside configuration or regular expression I guess...

Answer (score 0):

As a proof of concept I ended up with this. Please don't use this without examining the consequences first.

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  upstream elasticsearch {
    server 127.0.0.1:9200;
    keepalive 15;
  }

  server {
    listen: 8080;

    # ES backend for search autocomplete
    # 1. Allow only GET requests.
    # 2. Capture the search_term which cannot contain the " character.
    # 3. Rewrite the request to the desired index's _search elasticsearch endpoint.
    # 4. Build the request body by concatenating the appropriate json with the search_term.
    # 5. proxy_pass the translated request to elasticsearch.
    location ~* ^/search/autocomplete/(?<search_term>[^"]+)$ {
      if ($request_method != GET) {
        return 403;
      }

      proxy_http_version                    1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection           "Keep-Alive";
      proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection     "Keep-Alive";

      set $search_prefix                    '{"query":{"match":{"user.name":"';
      set $search_suffix                    '"}},"highlight":{"pre_tags":["<strong>"],"post_tags":["</strong>"],"fields":{"user.name":{}}}}';
      set $search                           $search_prefix$search_term$search_suffix;
      proxy_set_body                        $search;

      proxy_redirect                        off;
      proxy_buffering                       off;

      rewrite ^.*$                          /my_index/blogpost/_search break;
      proxy_pass                            http://elasticsearch;
    }

    # All other requests go to the web application server.
    location / {
      proxy_pass                            http://server;
    }

  }

}
```